# Turning eval into int when filtering an html line

Tags: asp.net, int, eval

In my database i have 2 fields the Price field and the Discount field, Price being the price of the product and Discount the discount value of the product.

I show the original price and the discounted price near the product.

My problem is that i am having problems not showing the original price for products that dont have discount(discount = 0), i tried making an if that dosent show the line of code if the Discount field is = 0, but i am having problems turning the Eval to Int.

```
<% if ((Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Desconto"))) > 0){  %>
    <p><span><%# Eval("Price") %></span> <i class="item_price"><%# ((decimal)Eval("Price")-(decimal)Eval("Price")*((decimal)(int)Eval("Discount")/100)).ToString("N2") %></i></p>
<% }%>
```

It always gives me this error:
'Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.'

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: have you tried this '<%# Int32.Parse(Eval("Desconto").ToString())>'

Comment: tried it but forgot to mension that it always gives me an error, (edited the post).